# How to render asciidoc filename in asciidoctor template?

Tags: asciidoctor

I have a asciidoctor template similar to this one:

https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-backends/blob/asciidoctor-v0.1.4/erb/html5/document.html.erb

I would like to include a link into my documents which points to the asciidoc file that was used to generate the document.

*Is there a way to access the asciidoc filename within my template?*

I'm using the [asciidoctor-maven-plugin](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin) to render my documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the [built-in data attributes](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#built-in-data-attributes), I think that you are looking for `{docfile}` (evaluation depends from how the document is processed and when and where is it processed).

For me it works with the asciidoctor-maven-plugin (I get the absolute path to the file) but not in the chrome preview.